# Qgis C++ hello world example

Tags: qgis, c++

i am new in developpement with C++, i try to realise an application with C++ which can read and display a *.qgs file from Qgis, i tried the code bellow but it doesn't work, it always show me errors "no such file or directory"

```
#include <QtCore/QString>
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

#include <qgsapplication.h>
#include <qgsproviderregistry.h>
#include <qgssinglesymbolrenderer.h>
#include <qgsmaplayerregistry.h>
#include <qgsvectorlayer.h>
#include <qgsmapcanvas.h>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QgsApplication app(argc, argv, true);

QString myPluginsDir        = "/usr/lib64/qgis";
QString myLayerPath         = "pathtoashapefile";
QString myLayerBaseName     = "italy";
QString myProviderName      = "ogr";

// Instantiate Provider Registry
QgsProviderRegistry * preg = QgsProviderRegistry::instance(myPluginsDir);

QgsVectorLayer * mypLayer =  new QgsVectorLayer(myLayerPath, myLayerBaseName, myProviderName);

QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2 *mypRenderer = new QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2(QgsSymbolV2::defaultSymbol(mypLayer->geometryType()));


QList <QgsMapCanvasLayer> myLayerSet;

mypLayer->setRendererV2(mypRenderer);
if (mypLayer->isValid())
{
    qDebug("Layer is valid");
}
else
{
    qDebug("Layer is NOT valid");
}

// Add the Vector Layer to the Layer Registry
QgsMapLayerRegistry::instance()->addMapLayer(mypLayer, TRUE);
// Add the Layer to the Layer Set
myLayerSet.append(QgsMapCanvasLayer(mypLayer, TRUE));

// Create the Map Canvas
QgsMapCanvas * mypMapCanvas = new QgsMapCanvas(0, 0);
mypMapCanvas->setExtent(mypLayer->extent());
mypMapCanvas->enableAntiAliasing(true);
mypMapCanvas->setCanvasColor(QColor(255, 255, 255));
mypMapCanvas->freeze(false);
// Set the Map Canvas Layer Set
mypMapCanvas->setLayerSet(myLayerSet);
mypMapCanvas->setVisible(true);
mypMapCanvas->refresh();

return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Is the error the output of the program, the compiler or the linker?

Comment: when i try to compile the programme it show "Qstring no such file or directory" compilation terminated.

Comment: Make sure the needed paths are in your include path. Check -I for g++ or set include paths of your project correctly. This is basic functionality of the compiler.

Comment: acctualy i used the code here   ( http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112829/looking-for-qgis-2-4-c-hello-world-example/188963#188963 ) i don't know if there is a  qgis lib i should install ?!

Comment: You definitely need qgis. The include and lib dirs can be found under the installation, eg C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\include .

Comment: i checked the include in the installation of Qgis and it seems everything is good, is that's how i must define variables ? because i think the probleme is here :

QString myPluginsDir        = "C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen";
QString myLayerPath         = "C:\Users\Adnan\Desktop\testGis";
QString myLayerBaseName     = "testmap";
QString myProviderName      = "ogr";

Answer (score 1):

I was at that point a few hours ago; I was following [this guide](http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/doc/manual/qgis-1.1.0_coding-compilation_guide_en.pdf), nice although outdated.

It seems your code are missing some headers. Try adding these:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
```

Your makefile may also need these modifications (in Windows, check the corresponding configurations in the tools you're using):

```
INCPATH       = -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtXml -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qgis -I. -I.

LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS)  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQtXml -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread -lqgis_core
```