# Updated version of QGIS coding and compilation guide

Tags: qgis, c++, references

Is there an updated version of QGIS coding and compilation guide?

The current version is clearly outdated. I have been trying to compile the first example, 1_hello_world_qgis_style, though to no avail regrettably. I then adjusted my code as suggested by [Tiggey](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/39738/tiggey) [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112829/looking-for-qgis-2-4-c-hello-world-example). I suppose something must be wrong with the include files as I'm still unable to compile.

My platform is Windows/cygwin; I'm using the OSGeo4W64 packages. This is the code I'm using:

```
//
// QGIS Includes
//
#include <qgsapplication.h>
#include <qgsproviderregistry.h>
#include <qgssinglesymbolrendererv2.h>
#include <qgsmaplayerregistry.h>
#include <qgsvectorlayer.h>
#include <qgsmapcanvas.h>
//
// Qt Includes
//
#include <QString>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) 
{
  // Start the Application
  QgsApplication app(argc, argv, true);

  QString myPluginsDir        = "/cygdrive/c/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis";
  QString myLayerPath         = "/cygdrive/c/Users/defloriv/Documents/qgis/qgis_sample_data/shapefiles";
  QString myLayerBaseName     = "regions";
  QString myProviderName      = "ogr";


// Instantiate Provider Registry
QgsProviderRegistry * preg = QgsProviderRegistry::instance(myPluginsDir);

QgsVectorLayer * mypLayer =  new QgsVectorLayer(myLayerPath, myLayerBaseName, myProviderName);

QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2 *mypRenderer = new QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2(QgsSymbolV2::defaultSymbol(mypLayer->geometryType()));


QList <QgsMapCanvasLayer> myLayerSet;

mypLayer->setRendererV2(mypRenderer);
if (mypLayer->isValid())
{
    qDebug("Layer is valid");
}
else
{
    qDebug("Layer is NOT valid");
}

// Add the Vector Layer to the Layer Registry
QgsMapLayerRegistry::instance()->addMapLayer(mypLayer, TRUE);
// Add the Layer to the Layer Set
myLayerSet.append(QgsMapCanvasLayer(mypLayer, TRUE));

// Create the Map Canvas
QgsMapCanvas * mypMapCanvas = new QgsMapCanvas(0, 0);
mypMapCanvas->setExtent(mypLayer->extent());
mypMapCanvas->enableAntiAliasing(true);
mypMapCanvas->setCanvasColor(QColor(255, 255, 255));
mypMapCanvas->freeze(false);
// Set the Map Canvas Layer Set
mypMapCanvas->setLayerSet(myLayerSet);
mypMapCanvas->setVisible(true);
mypMapCanvas->refresh();

return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: The guide explains MSYS and Visual Studio builds. Why do you try cygwin? Could you add error messages to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of QgsVectorLayer should point directly to a shapefile (not a dir).

I had a lot of trouble to compile C++ code using Qgis API. At [QT C++ application using QGIS API](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244373) you can see the configuration that worked for me.