# What toolchain for a Win10 C++/Qt QGis custom application based on QGis v3.20?

Tags: qgis-3, c++, qt, windows-10, visual-c++

We have a C++/Qt application based on the KDE Marble library. I would like to replace the Marble library with the QGis library. However it is not too easy to figure out the correct environment for this.
Assuming I want to start from a recent version of QGIS (3.20.1 is just released). I installed the qgis-dev-full which seems to be v3.19.
I could read in different posts that the official release is built with MSVC?

- Which would be the actual version for this? 2015 or the newest 2019?
- Do I need a specific revision of Qt too?

There a couple of Q&As which are years old and no longer accurate:

- [QT C++ application using QGIS API](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244373/qt-c-application-using-qgis-api)
- [Using QGIS C++ API In Custom GIS Application](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365057/using-qgis-c-api-in-custom-gis-application)

The most recent is here, but doesn't have an answer: [Setup standalone Qt/C++ app with QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397969/setup-standalone-qt-c-app-with-qgis?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.